# Application failed to start: Spring Boot setEnableLoggingRequestDetails() not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup SpringBoot web application. After fixing some issues, i've got a new one. Application starts, but an exception thrown, and load failed.

Controller is temporary, implementation will be added later.

Tried to delete overrided dependencies, but have no result.

Parent section was added to fix issue with dependencies

My POM:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <!--Logging dependencies-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring dependencies-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Marshalling dependencies-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies; -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAXB requested by Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

My Controller:

```
public class AuthController {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AuthController.class);

    @GetMapping
    public List<AbstractUser> findAll() {
            return null;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public AbstractUser findById(@PathVariable("id") Long idUser) {
        return null;
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Long create(@RequestBody AbstractUser userToCreate) {
        return null;
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody AbstractUser userToUpdate) {
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    }
```

My error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(Z)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Removing forced dependencies make these imports inaccessible

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DispatcherServlet.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html#setEnableLoggingRequestDetails-boolean-) method was introduced in Spring 5.1. You are mixing up Spring JAR versions by manually forcing `spring-webmvc` and `spring-orm` 5.0.0.RELEASE. Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE uses Spring Framework 5.1.3.RELEASE as per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements):

> Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE requires Java 8 and is compatible up to Java 11 (included). Spring Framework 5.1.3.RELEASE or above is also required.

Use the library versions provided by the Spring Boot, remove the `spring-webmvc` and `spring-orm` `<dependency>` from your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Removing these dependencies fails project to compile. Libraries shows as missing. Help please, I'm new to this.

Comment: @IhorDovhoshliubnyi this is a separate question, please post code example after you have removed the dependencies.

Comment: manually forcing to 5.1.3.RELEASE  ```spring-webmvc``` and ```spring-orm``` libraries fixes the issue. Application start normally. Could you help to understand why this happening?